# Extract GLM coefficients for one factor only

Tags: extract, glm

I am running a series of GLMs for a number of species of the form:

```
glm.sp<-glm(number~site+as.factor(year)+offset(log(visits)),family=poisson,data=data.sp)
```

Note that the year term is deliberately a factor as it's not reasonable to assume a linear relationship. The yearly coefficients produced from this model are a measure of the number of each species per year, taking account of the ammount of effort (visits). I then want to extract, exponentiate and index (relative to the last year) the year coefficients and run a GAM on them.

Currently I do this by eyeballing the coefficients and calling them directly:

```
data.sp.coef$coef<-exp(glm.sp$coefficients[60:77])
```

However as the number of sites and the number of years recorded for each species are different this means I need to eyeball each species. For example, a different species might have the year coefficients at 51:64. I'd rather not do that, and feel there must be a better way of calling out the coefficients for the years.

I've tried, the below (which doesn't work!)

```
> coef(glm.sp)["year"]
<NA> 
  NA
```

And I also tried saving all the coefficients as a dataframe and using a fuzzy search to extract all the values that contained "year" (the coefficients are automatically saved in the format yearXXXX-YY).

I'm certain I'm missing something simple, so would very much appreciate being proded in the right direction!

Thanks
Matt